# List User Comments on User Profile BuddyPress

Tags: comments, users, buddypress, profiles

Does anyone know if there’s a way to create an option on the BuddyPress user profiles where it can list the users’ comments, so that the user can see a list of everything they commented on. I searched to find a plugin, but came up empty-handed.

Comment: This seems like asking for plugin recommendation or ready made solution. Please try to focus questions on more specific issues and include what you have tried, rather than looking for start to finish solution.